# How to create node property key with whitespace in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j, I want to create a property where key is not a single element. I need to create with space. How to do this in neo4j?

For Example,

```
CREATE (matrix:Movie {title: "The Matrix"})
```

I can create a property called title. But I want to do something like below,

```
CREATE (matrix:Movie {"new title": "The Matrix"})
```

It throws me  following error,

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '"': expected whitespace, a property key name, '}', an identifier or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21))
>   "MERGE (matrix:Movie {"new title": "The Matrix"})"

Basically I thought, `""` will help me to solve this problem. But it's working only for property value not for property key. How to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks ` around your property name to accommodate spaces.

For example,

```
CREATE (matrix:Movie {`new title`: "The Matrix"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution